# react router, listen to push requests

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I am working on a webs site which uses framer motion and next.js, the problem is that I need to remove a class that allow animations to happen before the path changes.

At first i tried

```
import {useRouter} from  'next/router'

export default function Projects(){

const [animated,setAnimated] = useState(true)
const {asPath} = useRouter()
useEffect(() => {
  if(asPath!== '/projects'){
    setAnimated(false)
  }else{
    setAnimated(true)
  }
},[asPath])




return(
        <div  className={styles.activeLayer}>
          <Image  layout="fill"  height='100%'src={allProjects[currentDisplay].backgroundImg}  alt=""/>
          <div className={`${styles.descriptionBox} + ${(**animated** ? styles.animatedOne:'')}`}>
            <h2>
              SomeTitle
            </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Modi excepturi esse ex odit saepe ipsam facere beatae similique doloremque quo quidem tempore quas molestias, commodi corporis natus possimus atque voluptatem?</p>

            <div className={`${styles.iconComponent} + ${(animated ? styles.animatedFive:'')}`}>
              <Tool  imgArray={allProjects[currentDisplay].tools} />
            </div>
```

this doesn't work cause animations run for a millisecond before it changes, and it actually needs to listen to the push request from a `<Link>`, but I don't know how to do it.

,

Comment: Why are you storing derived "state" in state? It's a React anti-pattern. Why can't you just use the `asPath !== '/projects'` comparison result boolean value? What links are you referring to? Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example for what you are trying to do, and more clearly explain the issue? See [mcve].

Comment: Edited the post. 
So i was using it to make it easier to read the code and when not using React useState some bugs occurs(the class is not set on initial load, may be because different from useState and useEffect actually runs on client side) when page reloading or when the path is '/projects#' for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap it. Set the state to default as false.

```
import {useRouter} from  'next/router'
const [animated,setAnimated] = useState(false)

const {asPath} = useRouter()


useEffect(() => {
  if(asPath !== '/projects'){
    setAnimated(false)
  }else{
    setAnimated(true)
  }
},[asPath])
```

Comment: the problem is actually when the page leaves /projects,  so the initial state doesn't affect my problem. I am trying to work with transitions and some elements gotta stop animating before page leaves.
sorry for not giving full info

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with some possibly incorrect initial state and using the `useEffect` hook to update it after the initial render, just set the correct initial state.

Example:

```
import { useRouter } from  'next/router';

export default function Projects() {
  const {asPath} = useRouter();

  const animated = asPath === '/projects';

  return (
    <div className={styles.activeLayer}>
      <Image
        layout="fill"
        height='100%'
        src={allProjects[currentDisplay].backgroundImg}
        alt=""
      />
      <div
        className={`${styles.descriptionBox} + ${animated
          ? styles.animatedOne : ''}`
        }
      >
        <h2>SomeTitle</h2>
        <p>....</p>

        <div
          className={`${styles.iconComponent} + ${animated
            ? styles.animatedFive : ''}`
          }
        >
          <Tool imgArray={allProjects[currentDisplay].tools} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`animated` is what could be considered derived state and it's often considered a React anti-pattern to store derived state in React state. Just use the `asPath === '/projects'` value directly.

Example:

```
import { useRouter } from  'next/router';

export default function Projects() {
  const {asPath} = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className={styles.activeLayer}>
      <Image
        layout="fill"
        height='100%'
        src={allProjects[currentDisplay].backgroundImg}
        alt=""
      />
      <div
        className={`${styles.descriptionBox} + ${animated
          ? styles.animatedOne : ''}`
        }
      >
        <h2>SomeTitle</h2>
        <p>.....</p>

        <div
          className={`${styles.iconComponent} + ${animated
            ? styles.animatedFive : ''}`
          }
        >
          <Tool imgArray={allProjects[currentDisplay].tools} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```